# Parsing csv files using delimitedText mode but generating only a single document in the search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I would like to take advantage of the delimitedText parsing mode for extracting fields from csv files so that I can configure things like faceted search on those fields.

By design, the delimitedText parser will generate one index document for every line in the csv files.

Is it possible to configure the delimited text parser to generate only one index document by csv file like the plain text parser but still be able to do faceted search on the values contained in the csv file rows ?

I try the delimited text parser with the basic configuration. I was expecting (hoping) to have more control on the generation of the index documents.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `delimitedText parser` does not provide a built-in way to generate a single index document per CSV file.

So, if you want to generate only one index document per CSV file but still perform faceted search on the values, you might need to preprocess the CSV files and transform them into a format that can be indexed as a single document while preserving the necessary information for faceted search.

One possible approach is to convert the CSV files into JSON format.
Then, you can use the JSON parsing mode in Azure Cognitive Search to index the file as a single document.

Below is sample scenario to convert CSV into JSON and use Json data in Indexing.

I have taken a sample CSV data:

[image]

I have converted the CSV data to JSON Format using below script:

```py
import csv
import json

csv_file = 'data.csv'
json_file = 'data.json'

# Read the CSV data
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]

# Write the JSON data
with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

With this I got the data in JSON format:

[image]

Then, I have created the index with below schema and uploaded the data:

```py
index_definition = {
    "name": index_name,
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": True, "searchable": False, "facetable": False, "filterable": False},
        {"name": "category", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": True, "facetable": True, "filterable": True},
        {"name": "brand", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": True, "facetable": True, "filterable": True},
        {"name": "price", "type": "Edm.Double", "searchable": False, "facetable": True, "filterable": True},
        {"name": "rating", "type": "Edm.Int32", "searchable": False, "facetable": True, "filterable": True}
    ]
}
```

The data successfully uploaded in the Index and with below code snippet I was able to search in document.

```py
url = f"https://{service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{index_name}/docs/search?api-version={api_version}"

headers = {
    "api-key": api_key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
payload = {
    "search": "laptops",
    "facets": ["category", "brand"],
    "count": True
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
results = response.json()

print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```py
  "@odata.count": 2,
  "@search.facets": {
    "brand": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "Brand A"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "Brand B"
      }
    ],
    "category": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "value": "Laptops"
      }
    ]
  },
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.2876821,
      "id": "2",
      "category": "Laptops",
      "brand": "Brand B",
      "price": 1000.0,
      "rating": 5
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 0.2876821,
      "id": "1",
      "category": "Laptops",
      "brand": "Brand A",
      "price": 800.0,
      "rating": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

With the above method you can create single document index with CSV File.

**Note:** This is sample scenario for explanation, please configure and modify according to your need.

Comment: Unfortunatly, converting all the csv files to json all the time is not an option. I'm looking at custom skill to see if I could archive what I want.